# How Do I Create Tables Dynamically in SQLite in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite

I am creating an application where a table gets generated in SQLite Database as soon as a new user registers, but I can create tables only in the onCreate() method in the SQLiteOpenHelper class.
I am using this user-defined function to create tables dynamically :

```
public void createUserTable(DatabaseOperations d,String user){
    String USER_Q = "CREATE TABLE " + user + "(" + UserInfo.NOTES + " text);";
    SQLiteDatabase dp = d.getWritableDatabase();
    dp.execSQL(USER_Q);
}
```

but it does not work as I get the error while retreiving the notes column from the user table:

```
02-23 18:17:35.499 7292-7292/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) no such table: Bundle
02-23 18:17:35.500 7292-7292/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-23 18:17:35.507 7292-7292/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.himanshu.sqlregistration, PID: 7292
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.himanshu.sqlregistration/com.example.himanshu.sqlregistration.secretMessage}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Bundle (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT notes FROM Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=72]
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2339)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
                                              Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: Bundle (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT notes FROM Bundle[mParcelledData.dataSize=72]
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1316)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.queryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1163)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1034)
                                                 at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.query(SQLiteDatabase.java:1202)
                                                 at com.example.himanshu.sqlregistration.DatabaseOperations.extractNotesFromUser(DatabaseOperations.java:44)
                                                 at com.example.himanshu.sqlregistration.secretMessage.onCreate(secretMessage.java:24)
                                                 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6010)
                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1129)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2292)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:155) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1317) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
```

Code for retreiving columns from table:

```
public Cursor extractNotesFromUser(DatabaseOperations d, String user) {
    SQLiteDatabase dp = d.getReadableDatabase();
    String column[] = {UserInfo.NOTES};
    Cursor c = dp.query(user, column, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;
}
```

How can I create new tables with or without using the onCreate() method?

Comment: You seem to be querying the Bundle, not User table.

Comment: first post you full logcat !!

Comment: Read what you posted again. You want to retrieve notes column from user table. And then: `SELECT notes FROM Bundle`

Comment: how can it be a Bundle when i am passing a Sring

Comment: You have one table per user? That seems like a bad database design... Typically you have a table that contains the users and another that contains the notes and who they belong to

Comment: Why on Earth would you create a different table for each user? **This is against database normalization rules**. And common sense.

Comment: Your `user` param value seems to come from `Bundle#toString()` and I'd guess you wanted to call `Bundle#getString()` instead.

Comment: use a good frame work brother

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Error show that your table is not created, because you have put **`semicolon (;)`**   at the end of query so write proper like below, its create runtime when you call this function.

```
public void createUserTable(DatabaseOperations d, String user) {
    final SQLiteDatabase db = getWritableDatabase();
    String CREATE_TABLE_NEW_USER = "CREATE TABLE " + user + " (" + UserInfo.NOTES + " TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_NEW_USER);
    db.close();
}
```

Comment: @theSereneRebel always happy to help..!!

Comment: can you tell me how to create  table in   `room database` dynamically ?